# How can I create a caching object factory in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I want to develop a library for boolean formulas with Rust and I'm pretty new to Rust.

The idea is to have immutable formulas which are created and cached by a (obviously mutable) formula factory. So a user would first create a formula factory and then use it to create formulas which are returned as references.

The problem is that the compiler basically does not let me create more than one formula, because this would mean that there is more than one mutable borrow of the formula factory object.

```rust
let mut f = FormulaFactory::new();
let a = f.variable("a");
let b = f.variable("b"); // error: cannot borrow `f` as mutable more than once at a time
let ab = f.and(a, b);
```

I understand this violation of rules, but on the other hand I think that in this case everything would be ok (at least in a single-threaded setting). Is there a simple way to get around this problem or do I rather have to think about a different, more rust-compatible approach?

Some more information: `'static` lifetime is not an option in the targeted scenario. The user might want to create multiple formula factories and especially drop them if the formulas are no longer needed.

Just for reference a minimal example (strongly simplified – obviously a `Formula` will also have a formula type, in this example there are only variables and conjunctions):

```rust
#![feature(hash_set_entry)]
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct Formula<'a> {
    variable: Option<&'a str>,
    operands: Vec<&'a Formula<'a>>,
}

pub struct FormulaFactory<'a> {
    variables: HashSet<Formula<'a>>,
    conjunctions: HashSet<Formula<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> FormulaFactory<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> FormulaFactory<'a> {
        FormulaFactory {
            variables: HashSet::new(),
            conjunctions: HashSet::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn variable(&mut self, name: &'a str) -> &Formula<'a> {
        (&mut self.variables).get_or_insert(Formula{variable: Some(name), operands: vec![]})
    }
    
    pub fn and(&mut self, op1: &'a Formula<'a>, op2: &'a Formula<'a>) -> &Formula<'a> {
        (&mut self.conjunctions).get_or_insert(Formula{variable: None, operands: vec![op1, op2]})
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = FormulaFactory::new();
    let a = f.variable("a");
    let b = f.variable("b"); // error: cannot borrow `f` as mutable more than once at a time
    let ab = f.and(a, b);
    
    println!("{}", ab.operands[0].variable.unwrap())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `a` is a reference contained in the `f` object. As long as you have references of `a` you cannot modify `f` as it already aliased by `a`. I think the best way to approach this would be to have a `Vec` of `Formula` in the `FormulaFactory` struct called `formulas` (for the sake of simplicity) and give out only `FormulaIndex` objects which is just a `usize` representing the index of the `Formula` within the `formulas` field. This is the same approach that [petgraph](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/petgraph/) takes where the `nodes` field in a `Graph` contains a `Vec` of `Node` but the `Graph` api only gives out `NodeIndex` objects.